# Angular Compiler Error (seems to be the wrong instance)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

when I try to run "ng serve" I run into the following issue:

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module build failed: Error: Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
>   This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.

Following this suggestion:

> $ npm ls @ngtools/webpack
>   test@0.0.0 C:\Daten\Projects\test
>    `-- @angular/cli@1.7.2`
>   -- @ngtools/webpack@1.10.1

So there are no multiple webpack versions installed. I tried to reinstall `@angular/cli` for multiple times....globally, locally, after using `npm cache clean -f` and `npm cache verify`. I did the same with `webpack`. Sadly there are not really many other people running into this issue, what makes it hard to solve. My google researches were not successfull due to all i could found was a chinese page translating that error into chinese and these two SO links (which do not provide a solution for me):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Angular+Compiler+was+detected

[Error: several @ngtools/webpack packages installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774405/error-several-ngtools-webpack-packages-installed)

[Share `node_modules` between Meteor 1.6 server & Angular CLI client Angular-Meteor subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094987/share-node-modules-between-meteor-1-6-server-angular-cli-client-angular-mete)

my package.json:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**note:**

The project can be compiled at another PC - the only difference is the OS (he uses win7 while i use win10).

greetings and have a nice week end,

Messerbill

Comment: Have you tried deleting node modules and doing `npm install`

Comment: @BhushanBabar there is nearly nothing else i did during the last days...deleting `node_modules`, afterwards `npm cache clean -f` and `npm cache verify` and then again `npm install` - still same error

Comment: Can you check if you accidentally have a globally installed webpack? `npm ls -g`

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi yea, in fact i had a webpack installed globally. I removed it, deleted node_modules in the project folder, cleared npm cache and did `npm install` again. same error; there is still the webpack-dev-server installed globally. may this be the reason?

Comment: also without `webpack-dev-server` the error occures

Comment: all i have is an `angular@cli@1.7.2` globally and locally - this had never caused any problems before and i tried without the one and the other, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. Updating my **global** typescript version fixed it. Now using tsc 2.6.2 globally and it works.

Now using the following:

- typescript `2.6.2` (globally and locally)
- @angular/cli `1.7.2` (globally and locally)

  - webpack `3.11.0`
- node -v `8.9.1`
- npm -v `5.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Not sure if it is related to upgrading to Angular CLI 1.7.2 or not (I upgraded from 1.6.1).

This is what I did to resolve it:

1. Nuked the project `node_modules` folder (just running `npm install` didn't fix it).
2. Opened command prompt in Windows 10 as Administrator (may be overkill).
3. Ran `npm install` in project folder.
4. In the vscode terminal I then ran `ng build` successfully.
5. Then I ran `ng serve` successfully.

I see from the comments that you already tried some of this, but these steps worked for me :-)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "9.4.6",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
}
```

Comment: You could try looking at the loader.ts source code for clues: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/3a3993e9ed2aaba16734c31c5eb73615d27b43de/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/loader.ts

Comment: actually i try to reproduce the error on another system

Comment: Finally. Updating my global typescript version fixed it. Now using tsc 2.6.2 globally and it works.

Comment: Nice. I have tsc 2.3.4 globally.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete your node_modules, and use `yarn install` instead of `npm install`. It worked for me :)

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but this answer does not fit the SO requirements. This is more likely a comment. And I do not use `yarn`. I already fixed my problem by updating the global `typescript` version (like explained in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the extra copies and from the dependencies in `package.json`, you will need to use the save flag:

```
npm uninstall --save webpack
```

If you have installed the package as a "devDependency" (i.e. with `--save-dev`) then `--save` won't remove it from package.json. You need to use `--save-dev` to uninstall it.
Here is the outcome of the above command working good.

```
$ npm ls @ngtools/webpack
angularapp@0.0.0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.7.5
| `-- @ngtools/webpack@6.1.5
`-- @ngtools/webpack@6.2.1
```

---

```
$ npm uninstall --save webpack
> node-sass@4.9.3 install C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.3\win32-x64-59_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-59\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
added 1106 packages in 677.641s
```

---

```
$ npm ls @ngtools/webpack
angularapp@0.0.0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.7.5
  `-- @ngtools/webpack@6.1.5
```